# Low Ram Usage in Postgres CloudSQL instance?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a production environment setup with Postgres CloudSql instance. My database in around 30GB and I have ram of 8GB on master and 16GB on slave. But one weird thing happening with me is that the memory usage on both master and slave is stuck at 43%. I am not sure what is the reason for same. Can anyone help regarding this?

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `shared_buffers` and `work_mem`?

Comment: shared_buffers = 340480, work_mem = 4096 on master where Ram is 8GB

Comment: What unit are those numbers?

Comment: Actually, I ran the `SELECT name, setting FROM pg_settings where name in ('shared_buffers','work_mem');` on the database and got those results. Looking at these numbers, it looks like these are number of blocks rather than in KB for shared_buffers and in KB for work_mem. So basically shared_buffers = 2660 MB and work_mem = 4MB

Comment: Actually I cannot see these parameters from the .conf file as this instance is managed.

Comment: I cross checked using `SELECT name, setting, unit FROM pg_settings where name in ('shared_buffers','work_mem');` and the units were 8KB and 1KB correspondingly. I think I got the answer, increasing `shared_buffers` will help us. You can confirm it.

Comment: To anybody who finds this later, I recommend reading the manual page for shared_buffers because it will help you understand better (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/runtime-config-resource.html). For example it says that it will rarely be helpful to set shared_buffers to more than 40% of RAM, and it notes that if units are not specified, the number represents the number of blocks (i.e. you should typically multiply the number by 8KB to see what disk size it represents).

Answer (score 0):

I cannot tell what number exactly the graph represents, but I assume it is allocated memory.

Then that would be fine, because the "free" RAM is actually used by the kernel to cache files, and PostgreSQL uses that memory indirectly via the kernel cache.

Comment: But if kernel is using some memory to cache files, should I see it in overall ram usage or not?

Comment: Depends on what exactly is measured. You might want to ask the provider.